# Rails model test not railing when it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, testing, model, tdd

I am using Ruby 2.6.3 and Rails 6 as an API. :My model Item has fields name and price. My test is to validate that these fields are present. My test reads as follows

```
test 'Should have name and price ' do
   item = Item.new
   assert_not item.save, "Item saved without a name or price"
 end
```

This results in a green test which should not be happening because there are no current validations. Even when I add validations the test is still green:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true
end
```

With and without validations my test comes back green. What the heck is going on?

Comment: When I reverse the assert_not to assert it fails and in this scenario when I add validations it still fails. This is very strange

Comment: I'd buy you so much beer right now for that typo in your title. @ everyone else: please don't kill me.